# Tool to Monitor Performance of H2 Database

Tags: database, performance, h2, live, monitor

I wonder if there is any tool to monitor the performance of H2 database, such as IO, CPU usage. Live performance with graphs such as Oracle's Enterprise Manager. If not, is there at least anything like a diagnostic tool to give suggestions of missing indexes, etc?

[image]